# helm range get values outside of loop

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I was looking at the helm range example they have on their [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#looping-with-the-range-action).

**yaml**

```
favorite:
  drink: coffee
  food: pizza
pizzaToppings:
  - mushrooms
  - cheese
  - peppers
  - onions
```

**helm**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  myvalue: "Hello World"
  {{- with .Values.favorite }}
  drink: {{ .drink | default "tea" | quote }}
  food: {{ .food | upper | quote }}
  {{- end }}
  toppings: |-
    {{- range .Values.pizzaToppings }}
    - {{ . | title | quote }}
    - {{ .Values.favorite.drink }}
    {{- end }}
```

I updated it to have this line `- {{ .Values.favorite.drink }}` but when I run `helm template` I get the error

```
can't evaluate field Values
```

Is there anyway to access the top level `.Values` from within the `range` function and escape the loop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also use a global variable `$` that points to the root context

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  myvalue: "Hello World"
  {{- with .Values.favorite }}
  drink: {{ .drink | default "tea" | quote }}
  food: {{ .food | upper | quote }}
  {{- end }}
  toppings: |-
    {{- range $.Values.pizzaToppings }}
    - {{ . | title | quote }}
    - {{ $.Values.favorite.drink }}
    {{- end }}
```

Comment: plus, when using range, you may use template or include functions as follows.

{{ template "foo.bar" $ }} or {{ include "foo.bar" $ }}

Answer (score 6):

You can use a variable:

```
  toppings: |-
    {{- $drink := .Values.favorite.drink }}
    {{- range .Values.pizzaToppings }}
    - {{ . | title | quote }}
    - {{ $drink }}
    {{- end }}
```

You can assign `Values` to a variable as well if you prefer.

```
  toppings: |-
    {{- $val := .Values }}
    {{- range .Values.pizzaToppings }}
    - {{ . | title | quote }}
    - {{ $val.favorite.drink }}
    {{- end }}
```